# How do I ask a user if they want to play the game again?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, do-while

I want to ask the user if they want to play the game again at the end only if they guess correctly. If they say no I want to end the program. So basically yes-> play again and no->end program

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NumberGuesser</title>
<script>

var guess = 99;
var target = 0;
var turns = 0;
var msg = "";

target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
alert (target);

msg = "Guess my number between 1 and 100 !. \n";
msg += "Guess the number, and I'll tell you if it's too high, \n";
msg += "too low, or correct. ";
alert (msg);

guess = eval(prompt("What is your guess?", ""));

while ( guess != target){
  if (guess > target){
guess = prompt (turns + ".  Too high!! Try again!!", "");
  } // end if

  if (guess < target){
    guess = prompt (turns + ".  Too low!! Try again!!", "");
  } // end if

  if (guess == target){
    msg = "YOU WIN!!! \n";
    alert (msg);
  } // end if
} // end while

</script>
</head>

<body>
<center><center>
<h1>NumberGuesser<br></h1>
</center>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys, I'm having a rough time in javascript.

Comment: if you were to take a stab in the dark and guess how to do this - what do you think you'd need to include in the solution?

Comment: I very much appreciate you not giving me an answer and challenging me (seriously).

MY guess would be to have another while loop (nested?) to ask if they want to play again and somehow have it restart at the beginning of the last loop?

Comment: I'm a teacher as well as a developer ;)
Yes - a while loop is definitely part of the solution. So - what happened when you tried that approach?

Comment: a giant mess. I'm trying to make another loop inside of the one I already have. I really don't understand the concept of loops. I'm EXTREMELY new at this and purely self taught.. this is tough..

Comment: yeah - loops are. In this case - the solution will be to think about what you need to loop. Thinking about how you'd define what you want in english can often provide a clue.

Comment: You want to *do the whole program again* until they *say stop doing it*

Comment: I do. I tried using the below solution and to know avail. urrggggg

Comment: below solution won't work because the loop is only around the "tell me if you would like to do it again" part... you want to loop the *entire program* ;)

Comment: .. and now i'm lost. i know what i have to do, just not how

Comment: put the while loop around the whole program.

Comment: can you show that in context? i've done it many times (incorrectly)

Comment: added as an answer. I've left the prompt to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do the whole program again until they say stop doing it, so you need to put the while loop around the whole program (with the user-prompt at the end).

```
var guess = 99;
var target = 0;
var turns = 0;
var msg = "";

var keep_looping = true;

// this is the new loop. 
// The whole program is now inside this loop, so the whole program will 
// be repeated over and over until "keep_looping" is false

while (keep_looping) {    



   target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    alert (target);

    msg = "Guess my number between 1 and 100 !. \n";
    msg += "Guess the number, and I'll tell you if it's too high, \n";
    msg += "too low, or correct. ";
    alert (msg);

    guess = eval(prompt("What is your guess?", ""));

    while ( guess != target){
      if (guess > target){
    guess = prompt (turns + ".  Too high!! Try again!!", "");
      } // end if

      if (guess < target){
        guess = prompt (turns + ".  Too low!! Try again!!", "");
      } // end if

      if (guess == target){
        msg = "YOU WIN!!! \n";
        alert (msg);
      } // end if
    } // end while


  // now we're done with the program this time - we need to deicde if w want to do the loop again...
  // prompt the user if they want to do it again
  // if they reply "no"
  // then change "keep_looping" to false 
}
```

Comment: ah ok! ... now only to figure out the prompt... is it another loop?

Comment: nope - not a loop. You are already in a loop. Now you just need to ask them if you want to do this loop again. Literally add the code that the comments say to do.. :)

Comment: is there a way to prompt for 'yes or no'?

Comment: confusion accomplished. all im trying to do is immitate another loop? if not i dont know where to place it or what variable to use

Comment: We have the loop. The whole program is now inside a loop. That loop will run over and over until you tell it to stop (by changing the value of "keep_looping" to false).

Comment: You change Keep_looping to false if the person enters "no" to the prompt. How do you do a prompt? just the same as you prompt for a guess.... but instead of getting a number back, it will be yes or no. If it's "no" then you change keep_looping to false.

Comment: i'm using just about all my brain power here.. been stressed with this stuff all day.. only so much more i can take... i admire your patience..

Comment: Tell me how you write a prompt (using an example that you have already written)

Comment: if (guess == target){
    keep_looping = false;
    var keepp= prompt("wanna keep playing?", "");
    if(keepp == "yes"){
    keep_looping = true

Comment: "if not i dont know where to place it "
In the code I have written above, I have lots of comments that tell you exactly where to put the prompt.
"or what variable to use"
call the variable whatever you like - it doesn't matter what the variable is called, only what the value of it is

Comment: Ok, remember, you *dont need a loop* when asking for the answer here. The loop is already around the whole program. this is just asking the user *if they want to do this again*... and *if* they say no. *set keep_looping = false*...

Comment: so - your answer above is very close to being right... just remove the bits that aren't needed anymore.

Comment: 1) prompt the user and save the answer
2) if the answer is "no" then set keep_looping to false

That's it.

Comment: so instead..

var keepp = prompt("wanna keep playing?", "");
if(keepp == "no"){
keep_looping = false;

?

Comment: yep - that's it.
That coupled with the big loop around the whole program (`while (keep_looping)`) will make it all work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NumberGuesser</title>
<script>

var guess = 99;
var target = 0;
var turns = 0;
var msg = "";
var win = false;

target = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
alert (target);

msg = "Guess my number between 1 and 100 !. \n";
msg += "Guess the number, and I'll tell you if it's too high, \n";
msg += "too low, or correct. ";
alert (msg);

guess = eval(prompt("What is your guess?", ""));

while ( guess != target){
if (guess > target){
guess = prompt (turns + ".  Too high!! Try again!!", "");
} // end if

if (guess < target){
guess = prompt (turns + ".  Too low!! Try again!!", "");
} // end if

if (guess == target){
msg = "YOU WIN!!! \n";
alert (msg);
win = true;
} // end if
if(win = true) {
alert("Play again?");
}
} // end while

</script>
</head>

<body>
<center><center>
<h1>NumberGuesser<br></h1>
</center>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

It's really the same code, just I added an extra thing.  Obviously, you will need to edit the alert I added, but once you change that to accept the correct input, your all set.

Comment: I used this code here and the output leads to it starting with a random number before asking to guess. After guessing maybe 3 or 4 times a prompt says play again? not telling me I've won with only the option of ok

Comment: Strange.  Sorry I couldn't help!